# HashMap edit value and Iter Rust

Tags: rust, rust-piston

hi i have a function like that and a HashMap and the probleme is i want to iter and edit the HashMap but i have too much erro with a clone the code compil but the value of the HashMap

```rust
struct Piece(HashMap<(i32,i32), Couleur>);
```

```rust
fn press(&mut self, args: &Button) {
    let mut coco = self.0.clone();

    for (mut x, y) in coco {
        if let &Button::Keyboard(key) = args {
            match key {
                Key::Down => x.1 -= 1,
                Key::Left => x.0 += 1,
                Key::Right => x.0 -= 1,
                _ => {
                    println!("{:?}", x);
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

here the link of the full code if you need/want to try
[Link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e94200af0ac98d52bffb0bc54a57fc22)

and the dependecies of cargo

```
[dependencies]
piston_window = "0.93.0"
rand = "0.6.5"
```

Comment: Note that modifying a key in a `HashMap` in a way that its hash or eqaulity is affected is a logic error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you're cloning `self.0` to `coco`, the following for loop you're consuming the [`HashMap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html). So while you're modifying `x` you're not actually affecting the key in `coco`, as you cannot mutate keys in a `HashMap`.

Instead wrap the body of you for loop in a [`map()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.map) and then [`collect()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.collect) the result back into `self.0`.

*Also your `+=`/`-=` for the keys are flipped.*

```rust
fn press(&mut self, args: &Button) {
    let coco = self.0.clone();
    self.0 = coco
        .into_iter()
        .map(|(mut x, y)| {
            if let &Button::Keyboard(key) = args {
                match key {
                    // Key::Up => x.1 -= 1,
                    Key::Down => x.1 += 1,
                    Key::Left => x.0 -= 1,
                    Key::Right => x.0 += 1,
                    _ => {
                        println!("{:?}", x);
                    }
                };
            }
            (x, y)
        })
        .collect();
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to avoid cloning the whole `HashMap` up front, then you can use `.iter()` and `clone()` in `map()`.

```rust
fn press(&mut self, args: &Button) {
    self.0 = self
        .0
        .iter()
        .map(|(x, &y)| {
            let mut x = x.clone();
            if let &Button::Keyboard(key) = args {
                match key {
                    // Key::Up => x.1 -= 1,
                    Key::Down => x.1 += 1,
                    Key::Left => x.0 -= 1,
                    Key::Right => x.0 += 1,
                    _ => {
                        println!("{:?}", x);
                    }
                };
            }
            (x, y)
        })
        .collect::<HashMap<_, _>>();
}
```

or you could `mem::replace()` and `extend()`.

```rust
fn press(&mut self, args: &Button) {
    let coco = std::mem::replace(&mut self.0, HashMap::new());
    self.0.extend(coco.into_iter().map(|(mut x, y)| {
        if let &Button::Keyboard(key) = args {
            match key {
                // Key::Up => x.1 -= 1,
                Key::Down => x.1 += 1,
                Key::Left => x.0 -= 1,
                Key::Right => x.0 += 1,
                _ => {
                    println!("{:?}", x);
                }
            };
        }
        (x, y)
    }));
}
```

Also, I highly suggest using [rustfmt](https://github.com/rust-lang/rustfmt) to keep your code nicely formatted, not to mention that your mix of English and non-English names can create confusion.

Comment: thank you very much for your help i will try to use only English variable name and use rustfmt thank you very much

Comment: You don't need to clone the `HashMap`: you can do directly `self.0 = self.0.into_iter().map(...).collect();`

Comment: @Jmb No you can't use `self.0.into_iter()` because you cannot move `self.0`. Instead you could use `iter()` and `x.clone()` or `mem::replace()` and `extend()` (which I've updated the answer to include examples for)